# Logststash forwarder read error looking for ack: EOF

Tags: logstash, logstash-forwarder

I am receiving this error message every time logstash-forwarder has a new log to ship.  Eventually the connection gets made and logstash-forwarder output confirms that the events have been processed but I was hoping that there could a way to resolve this error.

Here is a sample of what is happening:

```
2015/01/25 18:51:46.116770 Read error looking for ack: EOF
2015/01/25 18:51:46.116831 Loading client ssl certificate: /opt/certs/logstash-forwarder.crt and /opt/certs/logstash-forwarder.key
2015/01/25 18:51:46.276102 Setting trusted CA from file: /opt/certs/logstash-forwarder.crt
2015/01/25 18:51:46.276453 Connecting to <IP>:4545 (<IP>)
2015/01/25 18:51:46.687068 Connected to <IP>
2015/01/25 18:51:46.736755 Read error looking for ack: EOF
2015/01/25 18:51:46.736857 Loading client ssl certificate: /opt/certs/logstash-forwarder.crt and /opt/certs/logstash-forwarder.key
2015/01/25 18:51:46.893790 Setting trusted CA from file: /opt/certs/logstash-forwarder.crt
2015/01/25 18:51:46.894110 Connecting to <IP>:4545 (<IP>)
2015/01/25 18:51:47.261252 Connected to <IP>
2015/01/25 18:51:47.343711 Registrar received 1 events
```

I am thinking there may be some timeout threshold happening, I have `timeout: 15` set in my logstash-forwarder config.  The Logstash server this is shipping isn't under any crazy amount of load but maybe there is something I can check there?

Comment: Did you ever figure out what was wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Apparently the protocol doesn't handle slow responses from the server [well at all](https://github.com/elastic/logstash-forwarder/issues/421). One user forked logstash-forwarder and made significant change to it in his fork, ["Log Courier"](https://github.com/driskell/log-courier) which might be worth a shot.

Comment: I almost forgot about this :) I have been fighting this issue off and on for awhile now, I have tried Log courier as well but it has issues as well.  I should probably update my original post with the newer stuff I have tried.

Comment: Log Courier seems to be working so far.

Comment: Thanks for the update. I actually somehow got logstash-forwarder to work well so I never switched. Not exactly sure what happened, but after a restart and fixing one host that had a bad SSL setup it started working.